# How do I deal with an array of input strings and make them match to an objects array keys even if there is nesting?

Tags: javascript

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-bhaskara-fohmt

For example I have an array of strings:

```
let inputNames = ['name', 'address[city]', 'address[state]'];
```

with this sample error object:

```
  let errors = {
    name: {message:"error in name"},
    address: {
     city: {message:"error in address city"},
     state: {message:"error in address state"}
    }
  }
```

When looping through names I would like to check the error based on the input name:

```
  inputNames.forEach(n=> {
    if(typeof errors[n] !== 'undefined') {
      console.log(errors[n]);
    } else {
      console.log('SHOULD have returned value of', errors.address.city);
    }
  })
```

Comment: Which part are you actually having trouble with?  There are 3 parts to this, the iteration, the reduction (to see if there is at least 1 error), and the sub property extraction.  If the last part is the one giving you trouble, consider how lodash implements [`_.get()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#get) and see if that helps.  There is not a native way to convert a path string like the one you described into a object access call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple and use lodash's `get` function.

```
const {get} = require("lodash");

let inputNames = ['name', 'address.city', 'address.state'];

let errors = {
  name: {message:"error in name"},
  address: {
   city: {message:"error in address city"},
   state: {message:"error in address state"}
  }
}

inputNames.forEach(n=> {
  if(get(errors, n)) {
    console.log(get(errors, n));
  } else {
    console.log('SHOULD have returned value of', errors.address.city);
  }
})
```

**OR** you can use plain javascript to achieve this using this function

```
function get(obj, path) {
  return path.split('.').reduce((parent, child)=> parent && parent[child]||null, obj)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the plain javascript version!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lodash`. `_.get(obj, key, defaultVal)`

```js
let inputNames = ['name', 'address[city]', 'address[state]'];
let errors = {
  name: {message:"error in name"},
  address: {
   city: {message:"error in address city"},
   state: {message:"error in address state"}
  }
};
console.log(_.get(errors, inputNames[1]))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```